# django-nocaptcha-recaptcha always shows additional verification box

Tags: django, python-3.x, recaptcha

I installed [django-nocaptcha-recaptcha](https://github.com/ImaginaryLandscape/django-nocaptcha-recaptcha) and integrated it into my form:

```
from nocaptcha_recaptcha.fields import NoReCaptchaField

class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    captcha = NoReCaptchaField()
```

It shows up fine on the form, but whenever I click on it an additional dialog pops up asking to enter some text and verify. It happens every time. I tested it from another computer on another network and it still asks for additional verification after clicking the box.

This is what it looks like: [additional verification dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaHkO.png)

Here's how I'm handling the form:

```
@xframe_options_exempt
def registration(request):           
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        clientform = ClientForm(request.POST)

    # check whether it's valid:
    if clientform.is_valid():
        new_client = clientform.save()
...
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it a problem with django-nocaptcha-recaptcha? Should I use something else?

P.S. I'm using django 1.7.1 with python 3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart the server and don't forget to clear your browser's cache. Hope this helps.

Comment: Amazingly, that somehow worked! I tried it yesterday too, but it didn't work then. I still don't understand what the problem was. Anyways, accepting the answer because it worked.

Answer (score 1):

[Another alternative](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=display&name=norecaptcha-python3&version=1.0.0): Minimalist and non framework dependant.
This is the code, in case you want to rewrite it.

```
 '''
    NO-CAPTCHA VERSION: 1.0
    PYTHON VERSION:     3.x
 '''

import json
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlencode


VERIFY_SERVER = "www.google.com"


class RecaptchaResponse(object):

    def __init__(self, is_valid, error_code=None):
        self.is_valid = is_valid
        self.error_code = error_code

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Recaptcha response: %s %s" % (
            self.is_valid, self.error_code)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__repr__()


def displayhtml(site_key, language=''):
    """Gets the HTML to display for reCAPTCHA

    site_key -- The site key
    language -- The language code for the widget.
    """

    return """<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=%(LanguageCode)s" async="async" defer="defer"></script>
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="%(SiteKey)s"></div>
""" % {
        'LanguageCode': language,
        'SiteKey': site_key,
    }


def submit(response,
           secret_key,
           remote_ip,
           verify_server=VERIFY_SERVER):
    """
    Submits a reCAPTCHA request for verification. Returns RecaptchaResponse
    for the request

    response -- The value of response from the form
    secret_key -- your reCAPTCHA secret key
    remote_ip -- the user's ip address
    """

    if not(response and len(response)):
        return RecaptchaResponse(is_valid=False, error_code='incorrect-captcha-sol')

    def encode_if_necessary(s):
        if isinstance(s, str):
            return s.encode('utf-8')
        return s

    params = urlencode({
        'secret': encode_if_necessary(secret_key),
        'remoteip': encode_if_necessary(remote_ip),
        'response': encode_if_necessary(response),
    })

    params = params.encode('utf-8')

    request = Request(
        url="https://%s/recaptcha/api/siteverify" % verify_server,
        data=params,
        headers={
            "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "User-agent": "reCAPTCHA Python"
        }
    )
    httpresp = urlopen(request)

    return_values = json.loads(httpresp.read().decode('utf-8'))
    httpresp.close()

    return_code = return_values['success']

    if return_code:
        return RecaptchaResponse(is_valid=True)
    else:
        return RecaptchaResponse(is_valid=False, error_code=return_values['error-codes'])
```

Comment: Hi Adrian, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
Please take a look here: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)